# How do you pronounce the surname "Cdebaca"?

Tags: pronunciación, nombres-propios

I keep seeing the surname "Cdebaca" in local news, etc. I understand this is short for *cabeza de baca* (cow head), but how would it be pronounced—as the full, expanded name, or an abbreviation (e.g., the Irish name O'Rourke) such as "saydebaca"?

I have yet to meet someone with that name so I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colorado politician Candi CdeBaca [pronounces it](https://youtu.be/8ItM25l-Fig) as /sedeˈbaka/ (i.e. as though it were spelled *Cedebaca* or *Cedevaca*).